# ClamAV for the host running docker containers - inotify/fanotify limits

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, anti-virus, clamav, cgroup

I'm implementing anti-virus solution for Linux with ClamAV daemon running in On-Access mode, watching the created/opened files for malicious content at the host system AND in docker containers, running at the host. What limitations I've found so far:

- fanotify doesn't work for files inside containers (by design)
- fanotify works per mount point (per filesystem)
- fanotify doesn't allow to implement OnAccessPrevention, using `OnAccessMountPath` directive in ClamAV config
- inotify allows to implement OnAccessPrevention
- inotify will not allow to watch `/` and Clamav will exit with error:

```
clamd: ERROR: ScanOnAccess: Not including path '/' while DDD is enabled
clamd: ERROR: ScanOnAccess: Please use the OnAccessMountPath option to watch '/'
```

To use OnAccessPrevention, you'll need to use OnAccessIncludePath (inotify) instead of OnAccessMountPath (fanotify).

- full signatures database is huge and must be loaded in memory (850Mb)
- scanning for windows signatures on linux box doesn't make any sense (I'm not scanning email)

So far, I've ended up with running two ClamAV daemons as [described at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043439/anti-virus-in-docker-container-does-fanotify-works-between-host-and-container): one for `/var/lib/docker` in `inotify` mode - `OnAccessIncludePath` directive in config and another for `/` in `fanotify` mode - `OnAccessMountPath` directive in config

Can I run only one daemon for entire host, which will do the scanning and will print notifications when maliciuos file was found?

References:

- [Filesystem notification, part 1: An overview of dnotify and inotify](https://lwn.net/Articles/604686/)
- [Best way to monitor file system changes in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381566/best-way-to-monitor-file-system-changes-in-linux)
- [discussion about different approaches to notifications in file systems](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bup-list/CXRI7MS3LwM)
- [Linux Filesystem Events with inotify](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify)